# SharePoint (WSS 3.0) Edit Page link missing

Tags: wss

I have a page used to display our custom webparts that's always worked perfectly until deploying the solution via a custom site template on a new server.

- On one particular page in a site, the Edit Page button is not in the dropdown.
- The Personalize This Page link is present on the malfunctioning page.
- Any other page (and any new page created) in the same site has the *Edit page button and not the *Personalize link.
- Adding `?PageView=Shared` to the URL has no effect.
- Adding `?PageView=Shared&ToolPaneView=2` allows editing in shared view from the tool pane, but I need the normal button to display for the page to work properly
- The malfunctioning page uses a custom master, but has always worked until this particular installation.
- The page is in the root of its site, same as the default page (which works).  It is not in a document library, and is not under version control or checked out.
- I was able to get rid of the personalize button by setting AllowPersonalization=false on all the zones.
- There are customizable zones on the page.

Any suggestions for how I can cause this page to have the standard "Edit Page" button option in the Site Actions menu the rest of the site.

Comment: Didn't realize that was an option.  Thanks.  How do I migrate?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and in the comment ask them to migrate it to SharePoint.StackExchange.

Comment: Since bounties don't migrate, I've refunded your bounty.